# Why the JavaScript could not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Index.html and stylesheet.css work well, but script.js could not work (it provides datepicker function), Why it could not work. I debug for some time. Could any one help me? Thanks.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pick a Date</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <h2><br/>Select a Destination</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <p>Departing: <input type="text" id="departing"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p>Returning: <input type="text" id="returning"></p>
        </div><br/>
        <div id="main">
            <p>Destination: <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="newyork">New York</option>
                <option value="london">London</option>
                <option value="beijing">Beijing</option>
                <option value="moscow">Moscow</option>
            </select></p>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #d0e4fe;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    background-color: #7FC7AF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

p {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    float: right;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
    top: 170px;
    float: left;
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#departing").datepicker();
    $("#returning").datepicker();
    $("button").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();
        var departing = $("#departing").val();
        var returning = $("#returning").val();
        if (departing === "" || returning === "") {
            alert("Please select departing and returning dates.");
        } else {
            confirm("Would you like to go to " + selected + " on " + departing + " and return on " + returning + "?");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have not included `jquery-{version}.js` (before `jquery-ui`)

Comment: Just copy paste my code and it should run. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include JQuery script before your custom JQuery scripts.
Like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Pick a Date</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
    <!-- You need this script too -->
    <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
```

This is because your custom JS Scripts use functions from the JQuery so it has to be loaded before your custom scripts.

NOTE: It is recommended to *include* Scipts at the bottom of body tag.

Plus you need to include JQuery before JQuery UI

Comment: "NOTE: It is recommended to use Scipts at the bottom of body tag." 
I did not use Scripts at the bottom of body tag?

Comment: I updated my answer :) thanks for that brother.

Comment: I meant include and not use.

Answer (score 1):

You have added. This will load jquery-ui

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js
```

but also need to include

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js
```

which will load jquery.

Also include jquery.min before any custom js files

I included version 2.2.0 which you may change according to your need

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. This line of code changed to the followling, then it can work(we should add "https:"). <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Your scripts are not being included in the right order and it doesn't appear you're actually include jQuery itself.

The desired order should be:

1. jQuery
2. jQueryUI
3. datepicker

In addition, the debug console would probably give you useful error messages which are clues about certain things not being defined when some scripts are being loaded.  That's a clue that some dependent script has not been loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you use a derived library of jQuery you must include the jQuery core first. I think that is what is missing.

You can find it here: https://code.jquery.com/